# foreach loop only outputs the last element from array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

I have made a select statment which has mutliple outputs.

But when i try to return it only returs the last one.
Here is my code...

```
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

$result = [];

foreach ($row as $fullName => $type) {
    $result['fullName'] = $type['name'] . ' ' .$type['lastname'];
    $result['class_type'] = $type['typ'];

    var_dump($result['fullName']);
}

return $result;
```

My var-dump returns 4 results but my return only returns me the last results from the var dump.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `foreach` if you construct your query properly:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, " ", lastname) AS fullName, typ AS class_type FROM table_name
```

Then just fetch all rows and return them:

```
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Hey i did try something like this ```SELECT profile`.rolle,
( `profile`.`name` , " " ,
`profile`.nachname ) AS full_name,``` but it returns Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score -1):

You are rewriting values in your code. You need to push each result to the array. See code below for reference.

```
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

$result = [ ];

foreach ($row as $fullName => $type) {
    $result[] = [
    'fullName' => $type['name'] . ' ' .$type['lastname'],
    'class_type' => $type['typ'] ];

   // var_dump($result['fullName']);
}

return $result;
```